# Is it possible to catch or hide an unmanaged exception window?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, exception, pinvoke

Consider following native code (which is unmodifiable for reasons):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <exception>

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void terminate_me(void) {
        puts("hello from C");
        std::terminate();
        puts("bb from C");
    }
}
```

Which  gets called from C# (which we can change in any way we want)

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("Project1.dll")]
    static extern void terminate_me();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        terminate_me();
    }
}
```

And this is what happening:

[image]

My questions is can we crash the app without showing this window to the user? I mean okay, something bad happened to the unmanaged code, just close the app with error code, don't show anything to the user.

Is it feasible?

Comment: Build a Release build?

Comment: In Release I don't even get the `Hello from C`: `Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)`. (I double checked correct target platform)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your C++ program isn't crashing; it calls [std::terminate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate), which has well-defined behavior. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to change behavior of calling external C++ programm. The only way I found for now is starting a new process so it gets terminated instead of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [_CrtSetReportMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportmode?view=vs-2019) functions, something like this:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void terminate_me(void) {
        _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG); // define that anywhere in your init code, etc.
        puts("hello from C");
        std::terminate();
        puts("bb from C");
    }
}
```

Note when `_DEBUG` is not defined (so, in release), calls to `_CrtSetReportMode` are removed during preprocessing.

Your `BadImageFormatException` error probably comes from that fact you've checked the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox in .NET project properties in release mode. This error is *always* a x86-x64 mismatch issue.

Comment: I commented above that I replaced `AnyCPU` with exact bitness, and this setting is shared across debug/release, and you have seen that I'm able to run it in debug. Back to your answer: unfortunately I can't use `_CrtSetReportMode` since in this example I'm only able to change C# code. I edited my question to match my implied restrictions, sorry for inconvenience. 

So, the question is if we can handle it without touching C++ code? (which is a closed source project shared as a binary).

Comment: But maybe `_CrtSetReportMode` is global? In this case I could just call this function from C# and change C++ code behavior?

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy - Yes, it's global, so you can p/invoke it (something like `[DllImport(@"ucrtbased.dll")] private static extern int _CrtSetReportMode(int reportType, int reportMode);`) . But depending on how you compile, it's not exported always from the same .dll. On my pc, it's exported from ucrtbase(d).dll (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2019)